# Put a view on top of AppBarLayout

Tags: android

I am working on a UI that utilizes the `CoordinatorLayout/AppBarLayout` combo as normally seen in most examples but there is this requirement of mine: I want to overlay the `AppBarLayout` with a View at all times. So, whatever scrolling behavior that happens, should happen under this view. Currently, this is what I am seeing:

[image]

Here, the blue bar that you see is the one that I want on top of everything. As you can see, it is hidden initially and only gets exposed when we have scrolled `AppBarLayout` off the screen. For your reference, here is the code for this layout and its id is **`android:id="@+id/linearLayout"`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.snapsboardmainpage.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/id_tab_photosvideos_albums"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/id_viewpager_photosvideos_albums"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.snapsboardmainpage.TopActionBarBehavior"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How can I achieve this overlay behavior?(*it would be preferable if this blue bar could remain as a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout`*)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although the question seems to be *difficult*, the solution turned out to be amazingly simple:

```
android:elevation="8dp"
```

Yes, that was it. Just set it on the the view that had to overlay the `AppBarLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

android:elevation="8dp" work on API level 21.

So You can put your view in side a new AppBarLayout.

In my case , i put my xml code in to new AppBarLayout like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="@string/app_name" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<!--i want below  view on the top of  app bar layout of id(android:id="@+id/app_bar")
so i put my all view inside the new app bar layout of id( 
android:id="@+id/longClickItem")-->

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/longClickItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_5sdp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/longItemBack"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/back_arrow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/longItemCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/longItemBack"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/longItemDelete"
                style="@style/long_press_image_view"
                android:src="@drawable/item_long_delete" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```